# can I control thread group while running concurrently in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have 30 different db queries. I want to run 5 db queries concurrently at any given time from 30 different queries. But it should not pick already executed query.

Like if any one query completed out of 30 db queries, it has to pick next query from 30 queries.

Can we achieve the above use-case in jmeter?. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

1. For executing queries concurrently use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) configured as follows:

   [image: Synchronizing Timer JMeter]
2. For picking up unique queries the easiest is using [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)

   [image: JMeter CSV Data Set Config]

Comment: Thank a lot . But Synchronizing Timer will not work as i expected.

Comment: i want to run 5 threads at any given time. It is not running as expected.

Comment: In JMeter you can have 5 concurrent threads or 5 requests per second. In the latter case you can consider using [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/).

Comment: How These Timers help me to check the SQL query (thread) completed.

Comment: I have 30 SQL in my csv. i want to run 5 SQL (threads) . if at all one thread completed it has to pick from csv and execute. it means at any given time 5 concurrent SQL (threads) should run. is these timer will help me out?

Comment: In that case it seems you don't need any timers, just use Thread Group with 5 threads

Comment: But it is only picking 5 SQL (5 threads)  out of 30 SQL from CSV.  Rest of 25 SQL are not executing.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working . 5 threads picking 6 sql's  concurrently. but it is picking random SQL. is there any way to pick sequential SQL.

Comment: Each thread should pick up the next line from CSV file. If your CSV file has one column only, you can consider using [__StringFromFile()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function instead

Comment: Why after adding ${__StringFromFile(test.csv)} in JDBC request still SQL's picking randomly?.

Comment: Each time __StringFromFile() function is called it picks the next line from the "test.csv" file. Take a look into the file to see the order